# Difference between cooking apples and eating apples

Tags: baking, fruit, apples

What is the difference between cooking apples and eating apples? With so many varieties of apples to choose from, how to choose the apples that are suitable for baking and cooking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many different varieties of apples, some are good for baking because they hold their shapes, some others do not, but can be good for apple sauce or jelly.

Most of the apples are good for eating raw.

There are many lists and charts available on the internets that show all that.

For example : 
https://bestapples.com/varieties-information/varieties/

or : 
https://www.theyummylife.com/Apple_Fact_Sheet